# Listing host's available ssh ciphers from client

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

Is there a way for a client to check available SSH ciphers and algorithm without using NMAP?

I have configured my sshd_config to disable some cipher and algorithm found by my security team.

Just wanna test myself whether those ciphers now unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *test* whether server allows an algorithm, the easiest way is to try to connect using it and see if server accepts it, like these examples:

```
ssh -oCiphers=3des-cbc [user@]host # or briefer ssh -c...; see below
ssh -oMACs=hmac-sha1 ditto # or briefer ssh -m...; probably should be rejected
# may need to specify a non-AEAD cipher to get valid test of a MAC
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 ditto # should be rejected 
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa ditto # ditto
ssh -oPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=ssh-rsa ditto # below 8.5 use PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes; ditto
```

'Best practice' today says 3DES should not be used; it isn't actually broken, but if you send gigabytes of data a passive adversary will probably be able to detect a duplicate cipher block occurred, but (with CBC) not that it was duplicate plaintext, which would be a 'break' in crypto theory but very unlikely to be of any use in practice. If you want to waste your time diving into this rathole, see crypto.SX or possibly security.SX.

hmac-sha1 and ssh-rsa or ssh-dss (both of which use sha1) are also not actually broken, but are no longer considered to provide an adequate margin of safety.

If you want to *see* all server-permitted algos except (possibly) client-auth, just do a connection with `ssh -vv` then look at this part of the output:

```
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
```

for everything but client-auth, and this (later) part (which may be omitted depending on the server software):

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
```

for client-auth (i.e. *accepted by* server).

Comment: The 3DES "64-bit block" weakness is probably entirely mitigated by SSH supporting periodic rekeying (including every X gigabytes), it's just that there's no good reason to still use it.